# SSH StrictHostKeyChecking non-interactive

Tags: scripting, openssh

Since v9 of OpenSSH StrictHostKeyChecking is the (IMHO sensible) default.

This makes that when the host key changes SSH refuses to connect until the host key in the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file is changed. This is no problem in interactive use, because the warning message is clear enough. But I have a lot of scripts which use SSH to execute distributed commands. A typical call looks like this:

```
ssh -nqo 'BatchMode = yes' "$chHost" "$chCmd"
```

which is then executed in a loop circling through all hosts. I am looking for a way to correct a changed host key within a script in non-interactive use. It is possible to remove the old key with

```
ssh-keygen -R "$chHost"
```

But after clearing the key the software wants me to interactively type "yes" to accept the new key and up to now I haven't found a way to do this in a non-interactive session. On the other hand I am loathe to change the StrictHostKeyChecking setting, because new host keys are then just added to the known_hosts file (and the old ones don't get reomved) so for one host there might be a number of (obsolete) keys in there and I'd rather have the file as clean (that is: containing only relevant and up-to-date information) as possible.

For reference the system I'm using is AIX 7200-05-06-2320 or 7200-05-07-2346 and the OpenSSH version is  9.2.112.2000.

Comment: StrictHostKeyChecking has defaulted to `ask` since long before 9.0, back to 5.5 at least. However, [beginning 7.6](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6) there is an _option_ `accept-new` which accepts the host key without prompting if there is NOT one (currently) in known_hosts. This is equivalent to -- and no more secure than -- answering 'yes' either by an automated method, or manually without actually checking the fingerprint: an active attacker can put up a fake host to intercept your connection, you see the key is 'new' and accept it, and poof your data is compromised.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: you have a point, but since I would use this method with an - externally provided - list of fixed hostnames the attacker would also have to install DNS spoofing first to reroute IP traffic to his host. In a datacenter where an attacker can install fake hosts AND his own DNS I'd say one has bigger problems than host keys.

Comment: DNS spoofing is not hard unless you run DNSSEC out to endpoints, which few do; hacking the DNS _registration_ is also common and defeats even that. And in a LAN you don't need to do _anything_ to DNS if you spoof the (correctly resolved) IP address. However, it's your data, so you choose as you like.